# How to do statistical inference based on randomly sampled discovery/replication sample?

Tags: inference, random-generation

I want to compute a score based on the association of several variables with my dependent variable and subsequently test the score's association with the dependent variable in an independent sample.

Unfortunately, I don't have a natural discovery and replication sample. However, any split of the sample would seem arbitrary and reviewers might suggest, that I picked the split that delivers the best results.

Hence, I thought the straightforward way to approach this would be to randomly sample like 1000 different splits. This means I compute the score in a discovery sample and test it in an independent sample 1000 times. Thereby I get 1000 beta values for the association strength. I would then perform a one sample t-test to see if the 1000 beta-values I get are significantly greater than 0.

I've already implemented this in R and it seems to work fine but I'm not totally confident, that this is a valid strategy or if there are any alternative/better strategies. Is it possible to inflate my t-statistic by simply increasing the number of random samples to like 10000 (I guess at some point it becomes asymptotic)? Is this legit?

Thanks for your help! I appreciate any pointers since this kind of analysis is rarely done in my field of research.

Comment: I did not follow the details on the computations you describe but the basic intuition (split the dataset multiple times and repeatedly evaluate the model on the hold-out data) is in fact a well-established technique called “cross-validation”. I don't know if this is a valid approach for your particular goal but using this keyword should help you find some relevant literature.